# Creating a custom url for an static html page

Tags: .htaccess, url, pretty-urls

I need to create a page like `http://www.example.com/strong` and the file to support that are inside my `docroot/strong/index.html`.

Inside my docroot there are other folders with their index file as well. For example

`docroot/site1/index.html
docroot/site2/index.html
docroot/strong/index.html`

So when user types in `http://www.example.com/strong` it should open `docroot/strong/index.html` without changing the URL. Can I achieve this?

Comment: if you have [directoryindex](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/urlmapping.html#documentroot) set as index.html in http.conf you have to do nothing.

Comment: I solved it by doing this on my .htaccess file   RewriteRule  ^strong docroot/site1/index.html/$1 [L]